# How to say "give different value to certain things"?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

There are these 3 things that in my view do not have the same (scientific) values. I mean, when I evaluate them, I give different degree of value to them. How can I say that? Does it make the sense I have in mind to say

> I value them differently.

or

> I evaluate them differently.

To me, above sentences mean "I evaluate them in different ways". But what I want to say is "I give them different degree of value". So I want a verb other than "give" to have the sense of "value" in it.

Comment: What is  a "scientific value" ? How objectively estimate  what is subjective. Is "estimate" the same meaning than "evaluate" ? Perhaps "grant" = "give" ?

Answer (score 1):

You can say that you are [***weighting***](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/weight) them:

> *verb, sense 4:* to assign a statistical weight to
>   *noun, sense 7a:* the relative importance or authority accorded something
>   *noun, sense 10:* a numerical coefficient assigned to an item to express its relative importance in a frequency distribution
>   <sub>*from [m-w.com](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/weight)*</sub>

Alternatively, you can say that you are *assigning different weights* to them.

This definitely conveys the idea that the techniques have differing levels of accuracy or correctness when used to evaluate something.  If your first technique is known to have a 20% margin of error and your second has only a 5% margin, you would naturally pay more attention to the second; you give the second "more weight".

Answer (score 1):

A word I do not hear very often is the word [accord](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/accord), meaning in your case to give deference to something or someone. For example,

> I accord different values to A, B, and C."

You could also say,

> "According to my [taxonomy](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/taxonomy) of scientific values, I rank A as of first importance (or priority), B as second, and C as third."

Another option is

> "I have a [hierarchy](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/hierarchy) of scientific values, with A at the top, B in the middle, and C at the end."

And finally, in my short list, you could say

> I [rank](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/rank) scientific values as follows: _____________."

Even the word *classify* could be pressed into service. If I didn't hate the word as much as I do, I'd also mention the verb prioritize. Oops, I mentioned it. Forgive me.

Answer (score 1):

Lots of good answers. Another is to use the word "rank."

"I rank them differently" avoids the possibility that you are assigning values that are non-comparable for some reason or other.

Oh, and "rank" as a verb avoids the verb "prioritize," which I view as a rank word.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use the word "give", then you can use the word "attribute."

> I attribute a different value to each of them.